# Getting error with using print statement in code to debug

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am trying to debug the code below so I have inserted print statements to print to my console so I can pinpoint where my code is crashing.

When I add the first print statement it tells me that it "expected to find ']'" but I have not used any new square brackets.  when I take out the first print statement this error goes away.

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CameraPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<CameraDescription>? cameras;
  const CameraPage({this.cameras, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraPageState createState() => _CameraPageState();
}

class _CameraPageState extends State<CameraPage> {
  late CameraController controller;
  XFile? pictureFile;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = CameraController(
      widget.cameras![0],
      ResolutionPreset.max,
    );
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return const SizedBox(
        child: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    }
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 400,
              width: 400,
              child: CameraPreview(controller),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              pictureFile = await controller.takePicture();
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: const Text('Capture Image'),
          ),
        ),
        print("Passed Test 1");
        if (pictureFile != null)
          print("Passed Test 2");
          Image.network(
            pictureFile!.path,
            height: 200,
          )
          //Image.file(File(pictureFile!.path))
        //Android/iOS
        // Image.file(File(pictureFile!.path)))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add print statemnt directly inside a widget. For example you added a print statement inside a column widget. A column can only hold widgets in its children property but print is not a widget. If you wish to add a print inside a Column widget use a builder

```
Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
          print("msg here");
          return SizedBox.shrink();
        }
),
```